# How to determine if the RecurrencePattern in Outlook is end by a date or end by recurrence count

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

For a finite recurring appointment in Outlook, the [`RecurrencePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern) interface doesn't expose a property to tell you if the pattern is end by a date or end by recurrence count. The `PatternEndDate`, `EndTime`, and `Occurrences` properties are always populated.

Is there a way to determine the end type of the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOM does not expose that property. You can

1. parse the recurrence blob yourself (not for the fainthearted).
2. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), use [RDORecurrencePattern](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDORecurrencePattern.htm).PatternEndKind property (rekNoEndDate, rekEndAfterOccurrences, rekEndByDate).